# With AngularJS, can I use json data to generate inputs and insert into the dom?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm working on a custom templating system. The user selects a template, an angular `$http` call is made and get the information about the template. Included in that json response is the inputs needed to populate the template:

```
{
    "template":{
        "title": "Test Template",
        "slug": "testTemplate",
        "version": 1.0,
        "inputs":
        [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "title",
                "label": "Header Title"
            },
            {
                "type": "textarea",
                "name": "intro",
                "label": "Introduction"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to use the values in each of the `inputs` to add that input on the page. I have to assume that I'll have no idea what inputs could be text, number, select, textarea, file, etc. I assume I need to use a directive to provide parameters to that will return the generated input then I need to add them to the page possibly as an `ng-repeat`.

Any help, links, or push in the right direction would be a great.

Comment: Do you know if json always contains `inputs` or can it be any HTML element and this example just happens to have `input`

Comment: @Rikin I'm the one that's going to define the json structure in the end. I want to keep it simple enough for other users. "inputs" is just a general term for any form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample code that I quickly made through and it works under assumption that json will always have inputs as zero or more.

`$scope.inputs=
        [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "title",
                "label": "Header Title"
            },
            {
                "type": "textarea",
                "name": "intro",
                "label": "Introduction"
            }
        ];`

`<input ng-repeat="x in inputs" type="{{x.type}}" name="{{x.name}}">{{x.label}}</input>`

Comment: I thought about that. It would work until I needed a `textarea` or a `select`. I could do something similar with a wrapper and an `ng-if` associated to it that repeats for each input and displays an element based on the options in the json.

Comment: Other way you can use is use `ng-bind-html` and have json populate entire HTML in property named as `inputs` or `form.elements`